# Make a formula based on a data table (Exponential function)

Tags: exponential-function

I always, since high school never found a good trick to do these kind of questions.

Lets say you've got a table (x and y)

> X: 1 2 3 4  5 
>   Y: 1 3 7 15 31

How can I make a function out of it? I know that it probably is a exponential function and that

> y = 2(y-1) + 1

however I'm stuck there. I'm not sure how plug it all in. I really need help for those kind of question since I do those often. If there's any procedures to determine a function base on a data table please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot. But ok, how exactly did you get there? Do you have any tips or procedures?

Comment: There can be infinitely many functions for a given table of course. One famous general method is known as [Lagrange Interpolation Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). You can type it directly into Wolfram [(see example)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolate[%281,1%29,%282,3%29,%283,7%29,%284,15%29,%285,31%29]).

Comment: Also one unrelated question: How do I make a summation decrement instead of incrementing?

Like this: $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=10}^{1} i$$

Comment: How would that be any different then a "normal" summation????? Also, please publish whatever question you have in the proper manner (i.e., not in a comment to some other question of yours).